# Почему JQuery работает только для одного элемента?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Всем привет у меня есть таблица, куда элементы наполняются через forEach, и есть JQuery скрипт, ajax который отправляет запросы на сервак. Но почему то мой скрипт работает только с первым элементом таблицы. Пробовал подключать скрипт и в начале и в конце body, не помогло. Почему так и как можно это исправить?

Мой скрипт:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.count').on('blur', function getTotalPrice(){
    var name = $('#name').html();
    var count = $('.count').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "cart",
        data: "name=" + name + "&count=" + count,
        success: function(data){
            $("#totalPrice").text("Total price: " + data['totalPrice'].toFixed(2)).wrap("<h4></h4>");
            $("#productCount").text("(" + data['productCount'] + ")");

            $.each([data['cartItems']], function(key, value) {

            });

        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
});
```

Моя страница:

```
<table>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Company Manufacturer</th>
                        <th>QTY</th>
                        <th>Prices</th>
                        <th>Total Prices</th>
                     </tr>

                     <c:forEach items="${cartItems}" var="items">
                        <tr>
                        <td><a href="images/product/${items.key.imageName}"><img src="images/product/${items.key.imageName}" width=100></td>
                        <td><span id="name">${items.key.name}</span></td>
                        <td>${items.key.category.name}</td>
                        <td>${items.key.manufacturer.name}</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="count" value="${items.value}"></td>
                        <td>${items.key.price}</td>
                        <td><span id="totalPriceForOne">${items.key.price * items.value}</span></td>
                        <td><a href="removeItemFromCart?name=${items.key.name}">Remove item</a></td>
                        </tr>
                     </c:forEach>
                </table>

         </div>
             <div align="right" style="color: #0087ff">
                 <span id="totalPrice"><h4>Total price: ${totalPrice}</h4></span>
             </div>

               <div align="right"><a href="order.jsp" class="to-buy">Make order</a></div>
```

Моя страница после заполнения элементами:

```
<table>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Company Manufacturer</th>
                        <th>QTY</th>
                        <th>Prices</th>
                        <th>Total Prices</th>
                     </tr>


                        <tr>
                        <td><a href="images/product/3.png"><img src="images/product/3.png" width=100></td>
                        <td><span id="name">ALLIANCE_SUNGLASSES</span></td>
                        <td>accessories</td>
                        <td>Luis Vuitton</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="count" value="1"></td> //сюда обращается
                        <td>810.00</td>
                        <td><span id="totalPriceForOne">810.00</span></td>
                        <td><a href="removeItemFromCart?name=ALLIANCE_SUNGLASSES">Remove item</a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><a href="images/product/2.png"><img src="images/product/2.png" width=100></td>
                        <td><span id="name">45DAVID</span></td>
                        <td>jeans</td>
                        <td>Collins</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="count" value="12"></td> //сюда обратиться не выходит
                        <td>100.00</td>
                        <td><span id="totalPriceForOne">1200.00</span></td>
                        <td><a href="removeItemFromCart?name=45DAVID">Remove item</a></td>
                        </tr>

                </table>
```

Comment: Использовать более одного повторяющегося id на странице запрещено. Избавьтесь от повторов (например, заменив id на class), а дальше уже будем разбираться

Comment: Изменил, теперь ко второму полю обращается но значение берет с 1

Comment: Разве к count не стоит ключи подбирать так же ?